# Is "Pure and Applied Mathematics Journal" reputable?

Tags: journals, reputation

I ask this question because there are at least several journals with similar titles, but I thought about submitting to this one in particular http://www.pamath.org/index. Is this a reputable math journal? It's not quite as big or reputable as publications from the American Mathematical Society or Springer's dynamics journals, but I don't want to assume this one is disreputable just because it has a similar name as other journals.

Comment: Following the link in the question to the journal's home page, I found, in the top screenful of content, two links for joining the editorial board. That does not inspire confidence in the journal.

Comment: The impact factor of $0.42$ doesn't inspire much confidence either

Comment: Hey, it has a 10-page proof of Fermat’s Last Theorem! Great journal indeed!